# TableCell segue to mapkit

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a segue to pass an annotation to the mapkit but when I test it alway end up in Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value [annotation is not a nil obj but mapView is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1aPV.png)

segue code in tableView controller

```
if segue.identifier == "FocusOn"{
        let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let controller = segue.destination as! MapViewController
        let animal = animalList[(path?.row)!]
        let annotationFocus = FencedAnnotation(newTitle: animal.name!, newSubtitle: animal.animaldescription!, lat: animal.latitude, long: animal.longtitude, newType: animal.type!, newPhoto: animal.photo!)
        controller.addAnnotation(annotation: annotationFocus)
    }

}
```

function in mapview controller

```
 func addAnnotation(annotation: FencedAnnotation) {
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: The segue is from table cell to mapviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the `viewDidLoad` was not called before the segue is done.

For that don't call `addAnnotation` in your `tableViewController`, instead send the annotation directly to your `mapViewController` and call the `addAnnotation` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

In your `mapViewController` you need

```
var annotation: FencedAnnotation!
```

In your `tableViewController` send the annotation to the `mapViewController` like

```
let annotationFocus = FencedAnnotation(newTitle: animal.name!, newSubtitle: animal.animaldescription!, lat: animal.latitude, long: animal.longtitude, newType: animal.type!, newPhoto: animal.photo!)
controller.annotation = annotationFocus
```

and call `addAnnotation` in `viewDidAppear` like

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
   addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the full picture based on what you've explained but I'll try my best to answer you. I would recommend setting a variable called annotation in the MapViewController. Then in your override func prepare() code, you should set that variable to annotationFocus. This might sound a little bit confusing, but try putting this piece of code in your tableViewController.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
        if segue.identifier == "FocusOn"{
            if let controller = segue.destination as? MapViewController {
                let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                let animal = animalList[(path?.row)!]
                let annotationFocus = FencedAnnotation(newTitle: animal.name!, newSubtitle: animal.animaldescription!, lat: animal.latitude, long: animal.longtitude, newType: animal.type!, newPhoto: animal.photo!)
                controller.annotation = annotationFocus
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I would put this into your mapViewController

```
    var annotation = FencedAnnotation()

    func addAnnotation() {
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addAnnotation() 
    }
```

When you perform segue, annotation in mapViewController gets set to annotationFocus. That's why you don't need an argument when you perform addAnnotation(). I hope this works.

Comment: I have tried, but when I click on cell the app crashed and error showed: thread1 :signal SIGABRT

Comment: Maybe change override func viewDidLoad() to override func viewWillAppear()